# Play Framework 1.2.4

Tags: logging, playframework

I'm in the following situation: I was writing the server-part of an application a few months ago and tested it only locally. Recently we setup a test-server (in the wild now) and I'm running the stuff from there. Everything works quite well, except the Logger. Whatever I configure in play, I don't see any logged messages in the ssh-session on the server. I'm logging into the server via ssh and starting play by command line there. I would like to have some Logger-output written directly to the system-out in my ssh-session. That would be the most comfortable for me. The same like running play locally.

Does anyone know how to accomplish that? Thanx in advance.

Comment: in prod mode the play framework keeps logs in a file. use tail -f logs/system.log to check real time log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx guys. Unfortunately none of your answers solved my problem in a straight line. But Greens answer brought me on the right track. The play version I'm using doesn't use a logs-subdirectory. But there is a file "application.log" which seems to contain the logger output. Unfortunately I considered the contents of this file as leftovers from running locally, because the servers timezone is not the same as the one of my local machine (so that the most recent logging-output contains strange times). I have to admit: it was my tiredness by the end of last week, that made me blind. Greens answer was by far the most helpful one. Thank you very much.

Anyway, my problem of having a comfortable logging to the system out is still open. Play doesn't dispatch to the system out when started with "run" on this server. This is a Ubuntu machine with play installed from the rep.

Answer (score 2):

If you deploy play to a server which needs ssh session to access, a good way is to use `play start --%prod` to start the server, where the log is redirect to `logs/system.log` in your project dir. When you want to view existing log information, ssh to server and go to the project dir and type `less logs/system.log` or if you want to check real time log, type `tail -f logs/system.log`.

Comment: Thank you very much. But how do I start play in dev-mode on the server? It seems my installation is always running in production, even if I start play with the "run" option.

Comment: Play start without --%prod should start the application in dev mode, unless in your application.conf you changed application.mode to prod

Answer (score 1):

Yes, log messages are redirected to the system.out default only when using `play run` and not when using `play start`.

The other difference between the two modes is :

**start**

- Launched as background.
- Précompiled
- Logs to logs/system.out

**run**

- Launch as prompt blocking
- Compile on the fly
- logs to default output